# What is the final distance between two ships if one heads towards ($\infty$,0) and the other ship always heads towards the first?

Tags: calculus

I just finished taking BC Calculus this year, and I read [an interesting question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31097/a-lady-and-a-monster) that prompted me to think up this one:

> There are two ships, A and B, traveling at the same positive speed on the XY plane. Ship A is located at $(0,0)$ and heads towards $(\infty,0)$ while ship B is located at $(0,k)$ and always heads towards ship A. As ship A approaches $(\infty,0)$, what does the distance between ships A and B approach?

I tried the question with both ships traveling at 1 unit/second, but I couldn't parameterize the x and y coordinates of both ships with respect to time. From my understanding of calculus, if the path B takes can be represented by a function $f(x)$, the distance between the ships will end up being $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$$

I couldn't find an equation to model B's movement, but I created a computer program to solve for several values of k and I received the formula:

> $\frac{k}{2}$ = distance between A and B

How is the formula for the distance between ships A and B derived?

Comment: Are the ships always traveling in straight lines?  If so then the $x$-coords are always $0$.

Comment: do you mean for the starting point of  ship B to be at (k,0)?  And, can we assume that the speeds of the boats equal?  If they are not then the distance will either be 0, or infinite.

Comment: Ship A always travels in a straight line towards $(0,\infty)$. Ship B always travels towards ship A, wherever ship A is located.

Comment: We might as well let the speed be $1$.  Ship $A$ is then at $(t,0)$ at time $t$.  Ship $B$ is at $(x(t),y(t))$ and we are given $$\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac {t-x}{\sqrt{(t-x)^2+y^2}}\\\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {-y}{\sqrt{(t-x)^2+y^2}}\\x(0)=0,y(0)=k$$ and we are looking for $$\lim_{t \to \infty} (t-x)$$

Comment: @Rob Arthan, Doug M: Ah, apologies! Either ship B must be at $(k,0)$ or ship A traveling towards $(\infty,0)$. The question has been edited such that A travels towards $(\infty,0)$.

Comment: Tilper.  The ship A travels in a straight line and x coordinate is 0.  But ship B never travels in a straight line as its always veering to try to head for ship A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both ships travel at the same speed.
Ship $A$ is at $(t,0)$

Ship $B$ is at $(x(t),y(t))$

$d = \sqrt {(t-x)^2 + y^2}$

the velocity of $B = (x', y') =(\frac {(t-x)}d, -\frac yd)$

$u = t-x$

$d' = $$\frac {uu' + yy'}{d} \\ \frac {u - ux' + yy'}d\\ \frac uD - \frac {u^2 + y^2}{d^2} \\x' - 1$

$d'-x' = -1\\
d - x = -t + C\\
d(0) = k, x(0) = 0, C=k\\
d +t - x = k\\
d + u = k$

As $t\to\infty, u\to d$  That is $y$ is very small, and ship B is tracking directly behind ship A.

$2d  =  k\\
d= \frac 12 k$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The velocities $\ds{\vec{v}_{i}\pars{t}\,,\ \pars{~i = A, B~}}$, satisfy
>   $\ds{t}$-independent $\ds{v_{i} \equiv \verts{\vec{v}_{i}\pars{t}} \equiv v}$.
>   $\ds{v}$ is the *common rapidity*.

\begin{align}
\vec{v}_{B}\pars{t} & =
{\vec{r}_{A}\pars{t} - \vec{r}_{B}\pars{t} \over
\verts{\vec{r}_{A}\pars{t} - \vec{r}_{B}\pars{t}}}\,v\,,\qquad
\vec{r}_{A}\pars{t} = vt\,\hat{x}
\end{align}

---

Lets $\ds{\vec{r}_{B}\pars{t} \equiv
\vec{r}_{A}\pars{t} + \rho\pars{t}\cos\pars{\theta\pars{t}}\,\hat{x} + \rho\pars{t}\sin\pars{\theta\pars{t}}\,\hat{y}}$:
$$
\imp\quad
\bracks{v + \cos\pars{\theta}\dot{\rho} - \rho\sin\pars{\theta}\dot{\theta}}\hat{x} 
+\bracks{\sin\pars{\theta}\dot{\rho} + \rho\cos\pars{\theta}\dot{\theta}}\hat{y} =
-v\cos\pars{\theta}\hat{x} - v\sin\pars{\theta}\hat{y}
$$

---

\begin{align}
&\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\cos\pars{\theta}\dot{\rho} & - & \rho\sin\pars{\theta}\dot{\theta} & = &
-v\cos\pars{\theta} - v
\\[2mm]
\sin\pars{\theta}\dot{\rho} & + & \rho\cos\pars{\theta}\dot{\theta} & = &
-v\sin\pars{\theta}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
\imp\quad &
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{\rho} & = &\bracks{-v\cos\pars{\theta} - v}\rho\cos\pars{\theta} -
\bracks{-v\sin\pars{\theta}}\bracks{-\rho\sin\pars{\theta}} =
\bracks{-v - v\cos\pars{\theta}}\rho
\\[2mm]
\dot{\theta} & = &\cos\pars{\theta}\bracks{-v\sin\pars{\theta}} -
\sin\pars{\theta}\bracks{-v\cos\pars{\theta} - v} = v\sin\pars{\theta}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
{1 \over \rho}\,\totald{\rho}{\theta} & =
-\,{1 + \cos\pars{\theta} \over \sin\pars{\theta}}
\\[5mm] 
\ln\pars{\rho_{\infty} \over k} & =
\left.-2\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta \over 2}}\,\right\vert_{\pi/2}^{\pi} =
\ln\pars{\half}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#f00}{\rho_{\infty}} = \color{#f00}{k \over 2}
\end{align}